# MySQL - get max of sum function

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get the maximum number to "max"
getting error:

> Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function    0.000 sec

```
SELECT max(count(*)) as max
FROM ticket
group by fan_fan_id;
```

I'm not sure what is the problem here and I will be glad to get some help here - also I need to solve it without "limit 1" option

Answer (score 3):

SQL does not allow nesting aggregate functions like the example you show.

The argument to an aggregate function must be a scalar expression, not an aggregate expression.

You can do what you want this way:

```
SELECT MAX(c) FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM ticket GROUP BY fan_fan_id) AS t;
```

Or an alternative is to sort by value descending, and return only the first count:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM ticket GROUP BY fan_fan_id ORDER BY c DESC LIMIT 1;
```